# Error in SQL statement (#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

```
SELECT add.id_address, 
       add.alias, 
       add.firstname, 
       add.lastname, 
       add.postcode, 
       add.city, 
       add.address1, 
       add.address2, 
       cl.name as country
FROM address add, 
     country_lang cl
WHERE add.id_customer=2 AND cl.id_lang=3 
AND add.id_country=cl.id_country AND add.active=1 
ORDER BY add.id_address ASC
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `add` as the table alias. It is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was already crazy.

Comment: No problem. StackOverflow is to solve problems and spread knowledge.
I am glad I could do the same. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

`add` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) you have to escape it or use other alias like `FROM address a` instead of `FROM address add`it like so:

```
SELECT a.id_address, a.alias, a.firstname,
  a.lastname, a.postcode, a.city, 
  a.address1, a.address2, cl.name as country
FROM address a, country_lang cl
WHERE a.id_customer = 2 AND cl.id_lang=3 
  AND a.id_country = cl.id_country 
  AND a.active=1 
ORDER BY a.id_address ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `backtick` if you want to use `reserved keyword` in following way:

```
  SELECT `add`.id_address, `add`.alias, `add`.firstname,
      `add`.lastname, `add`.postcode, `add`.city, 
      `add`.address1, `add`.address2, cl.name as country
    FROM address `add`, country_lang cl
    WHERE `add`.id_customer = 2 AND cl.id_lang=3 
      AND `add`.id_country = cl.id_country 
      AND `add`.active=1 
    ORDER BY `add`.id_address ASC
```

Beside exception, I would recommend you to use JOIN in following way:

```
SELECT a.id_address, 
       a.alias, 
       a.firstname, 
       a.lastname, 
       a.postcode, 
       a.city, 
       a.address1, 
       a.address2, 
       cl.name as country
FROM address a JOIN country_lang cl ON a.id_country=cl.id_country
WHERE a.id_customer=2 AND cl.id_lang=3 AND a.active=1 
ORDER BY a.id_address ASC
```